# Is it possible to change the revision number format in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, versioning

I would like to version my software following a *[major].[revision]* scheme. The revision is automatically increased with every commitment.

Is it possible in TortoiseSVN to specify a conditional, second increasing number, therefore achieving my desired versioning format?

I looked at the documentation, but found nothing. Results of a Google search mostly are concerned with the version number of SVN itself.

Comment: No, not possible.  I don't have a source to cite, because this is just something that's outside the scope of TSVN and SVN.  There are _many_ ways to implement versioning, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Like @PatrickQuirk already pointed out, it is not possible. How should SVN know whether you just commited a major version or just a minor improvement? You could consider to use additional software/ script to automatically change the version number in your software based on some keywords in the commit message

Comment: It would not be about "official" versioning, Visual Studio has the built-in feature to set your version numbers. I just wanted denote that, for example revision 437 was the first functional, running instance, with a second number. Surely I can document this otherwise, just wanted to check if there is something like this in SVN. Thanks for the info!